# Kafka consumer group script to see all consumer group not working

Tags: apache-kafka

When I execute the below command in kafka

```
./kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server sample-address:9092 --list
```

I'm facing the below error

```
Error: Executing consumer group command failed due to org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to find brokers to send ListGroups
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to find brokers to send ListGroups
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.wrapAndThrow(KafkaFutureImpl.java:45)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.access$000(KafkaFutureImpl.java:32)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl$SingleWaiter.await(KafkaFutureImpl.java:89)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:262)
    at kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand$ConsumerGroupService.listGroups(ConsumerGroupCommand.scala:132)
    at kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand$.main(ConsumerGroupCommand.scala:58)
    at kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand.main(ConsumerGroupCommand.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to find brokers to send ListGroups
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient$22.handleFailure(KafkaAdminClient.java:2610)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient$Call.fail(KafkaAdminClient.java:614)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient$TimeoutProcessor.handleTimeouts(KafkaAdminClient.java:730)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient$AdminClientRunnable.timeoutPendingCalls(KafkaAdminClient.java:798)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient$AdminClientRunnable.run(KafkaAdminClient.java:1092)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment.
```

Comment: What is Kafka version?

Comment: @AshishBhosle kafka 0.10

Comment: Try bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --list --zookeeper localhost:2181

Comment: ```Exception in thread "main" joptsimple.UnrecognizedOptionException: zookeeper is not a recognized option
        at joptsimple.OptionException.unrecognizedOption(OptionException.java:108)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of debugging, I have replicated this scenario and below solution working for me.

I have done changes in server.properties (that is mainly responsible for starting kafka server) instead of "localhost" pass **"IP address"** in listeners key.

Find detailed step below:-

These are configurations that you have to make sure while running a command.

1. Check for a correct IP address and port combination passed in command 
   bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server **192.168.X.X:4848** --list
2. Main important point , configure listeners with IP address in server.properties correctly .

   **listeners=PLAINTEXT://**192.168.X.X**:4848    --working**

   listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:4848            --Not working
3. Post-change, restart kafka server.

Note:- This issue generally gets reproduce/comes in virtual box. After changing network setting like NAT to bridge.

Answer (score 14):

In my case I noticed that we were using SSL

```
listeners=SSL://sample-address:9092
```

so I figured that I need to pass SSL properties in the command and it worked

```
bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server sample-address:9092 --list --command-config /kafka/config/client-ssl.properties
```

**client-ssl.properties**

```
bootstrap.servers=sample-address:9092
security.protocol=SSL
ssl.truststore.location=/keys/truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=*****
ssl.keystore.location=/keys/keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=*****
```

Comment: worked like a charm! I've a SASL enabled kafka broker so it was a bit different but main idea is the same.

Comment: I was having some other issue but using `--command-config` option resolved it!. Thank you, @gokulraj

Answer (score 1):

I use ip instead of localhost,it works for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the "Failed to find brokers to send ListGroups" problem but with the "Timed out waiting to send the call" exception.

In this case the problem was that the bootstrap server was not reachable from the machine where I was running the kafka-consumer-groups cli tool.

Since we have a VPC peering between our Kubernetes cluster in GCP and Confluent Cloud, I resolved the issue by executing the confluent cli tool inside the k8s cluster.